# How do you estimate long-run coefficients from ARDL bounds test?

Tags: cointegration, ardl

Can anyone explain this to me in simple english without too much complex algebra please? Hw and why etc.

Thx

Comment: https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html?m=1

Comment: I red David Giles blog post, but I still don´t understand why they are calculated that way.

Comment: Can you explain what part you have trouble with?  I’m not sure what you’re asking.  Long-run coefficients are not estimated from the bounds test.

Comment: "Step 8:
We can "extract" long-run effects from the unrestricted ECM. Looking back at equation (4), and noting that at a long-run equilibrium,  Δyt = 0, Δx1t = Δx2t = 0, we see that the long-run coefficients for x1 and x2 are -(θ1/ θ0) and -(θ2/ θ0) respectively." and in his example "we see that the long-run multiplier between US and EUR is -(0.047134 / (-0.030804)) = 1.53. In the long run, an increase of 1 unit in US will lead to an increase of 1.53 units in EUR." It is not clear to me why he does this. Why is the long-run coefficient of x1 = -(θ1/ θ0)?

Comment: Take the unrestricted ECM.  Set $\Delta y_t$ and $\Delta x_t$ to zero, since at long run equilibrium, variables are not changing.  Solve for y.